# Monitoring memory consumption over more than 1 hour

Tags: valgrind, massif

I am trying to monitor the memory consumption of a process for a long time with Valgrind's massif. The process is active and does some routine operations at specific time intervals and I would like to see the memory consumption of all the process.

I launch the process with:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --trace-children=yes <program name> <arguments>
```

My program is creating a daemon.

I see massif creating a file for the main process that exits almost immediately while the other one is still alive. When I kill the daemon process, massif outputs another file with the pid of the daemon. However, I notice that I'll get this second file only if I let the process run for no more than 15 minutes or so. If I let it run more, no file is generated. Valgrind shows no errors.

I suspect that valgrind is not able to handle such a big amount of information, is that correct? Any suggestion on how I could achieve my objective in any other way?

I am running the latest version of valgrind: 3.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If valgrind encounters a problem (such as an out of memory condition),
it is supposed to produce an error message.
A possible reason to have no error message when valgrind dies is to have
valgrind killed -9 or killed by the OOM.

What you could do to check this is to use vgdb in a loop in another window,
doing something like:

```
  while true
  do
     vgdb .... valgrind monitor command ...
     sleep 60
  done
```

As monitor command, you can either use a command to obtain the
internal state of the valgrind memory:

```
     vgdb  v.info stats
```

or, alternatively when running under massif, you can produce a memory
snapshot every 60 seconds or so by using

```
     vgdb detailed_snapshot filenameXXX
```

(you need to change the filename for each snapshot)

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver for more info about vgdb and monitor commands.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that I was using an init.d script together with 'service' to stop the process and that script was sending kill -9 command sometimes. Killing the process with SIGTERM by myself solves the issue!